# How to find time in seconds between two cross columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, select

The following sample data of table DATA_CUBE is in varchar(255). It has 1.8 million rows with no primary key. I want to return average time a bike spends at a station in seconds. To begin with, I ran a query to return results order by 1,4,5.From the below snapshot, what I want to know is if it's possible to calculate time difference between `stoptime` of row 1 and `starttime` of row 2 group by bikeid using SQL?

[image: Sample data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you really want is `lead()`, but SQL Server 2008 does not support that.  Here is a method using `outer apply`:

```
select dc.*, datediff(second, dc.stoptime, nextdc.starttime) as SecondsToNext
from data_cube dc outer apply
     (select top 1 dc2.*
      from data_cube dc2
      where dc2.bikeid = dc.bikeid and dc2.starttime >= dc.stoptime
      order by dc2.starttime
     ) nextdc;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, but this query is throwing error 8120. Do I need to use group by in the end of this query?

Comment: @ReeyaOberoi . . . No.  I originally thought you wanted the average and left that function in accidentally.